# Trouble with tick label format in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, formatting, labels, ticks

With `pgfplots` I'm experiencing some trouble with tick label format with some "higher" value of coordinates. Here a sample code which is working fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={\,}}]
            \addplot[red] coordinates{(1, 200) (2, 1500) (3, 9000)};
      \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But changing the of (3,9000) by (3,10000) generate this error:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/number format/at', to which you passed '(0,1)'
```

What's happening?

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you change the key family to `number format` and the next key after evaluating this is the position of the label which is a TikZ key. But because the current key family is `/pgf/number format` it appends it and hence looks for  `/pgf/number format/at`

Use `/pgf/number format/1000 sep` instead (you also have to turn the scaling of the axis too).

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `scaled ticks=false, yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd, 1000 sep={\,}}`. But I agree, for a single key it's better not to use the `.cd` functionality.

Comment: @Jake I'm a bit inclined to see this as more than a shortcoming but less than a bug.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Understanding this behaviour requires more knowledge of the internals of PGF and PGFPlots than a "normal" user should need to have. I think it would be good if the examples in the documentation didn't use `/.cd` at all, but just stuck to the full keys.

Comment: Thanks. Finally this : `scaled ticks=false, 
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={\,},fixed}` works to obtain the good format for me : thousands separation and no scientific notation.